# Calcular os valores automaticamente

Tags: jquery

Tenho um formulário onde o usuário poderá cadastrar mais de um passageiro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sendo que ele poderá escolher o tipo de passageiro. Vejam:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para cada tipo de passageiro, claro, um valor diferenciado. Ex.:

- Adulto: R$ 140,00
- Criança até 6 anos: R$ 60,00
- Criança de 6 a 12 anos: R$ 90,00
- Adolescente de 12 a 18 anos: 120,00

Como faço para que, conforme for selecionando mais um campo e conforme o tipo de passageiro, seja calculado automaticamente em Valor Total?

Vejam abaixo o código que tenho:

```
<table border="0" width="100%">
  <tr class='linhas'>
    <td>
    <table border="0" width="100%">
      <tr>
        <td  style="padding: 5px">
          <select id="TipoPassageiro" name="TipoDocumento[]" class="form-control">
            <option>Pax</option>
            <option value="Adulto">Adulto</option>
            <option value="Adolescente entre 12 e 18 anos">Adolescente entre 12 e 18 anos</option>
            <option value="Criança entre 6 e 12 anos">Criança entre 6 e 12 anos</option>
            <option value="Criança de colo de até 6 anos">Criança de colo de até 6 anos</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      <td  style="padding: 5px"><input type="text" name="NomePAX[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome do pax" value=""></td>
      <td  style="padding: 5px">
        <select id="TipoDocumento" name="TipoDocumento[]" class="form-control">
          <option>Tipo de documento</option>
          <option value="Carteira de Identidade">Carteira de Identidade</option>
          <option value="Carteira Nacional de Habilitação">Carteira Nacional de Habilitação</option>
          <option value="Carteira de Trabalho">Carteira de Trabalho</option>
          <option value="Certidão de Nascimento">Certidão de Nascimento</option>
          <option value="Passaporte">Passaporte</option>
          <option value="Cédula de Identidade Estrangeira">Cédula de Identidade Estrangeira</option>
          <option value="Outros">Outros</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td  style="padding: 5px">
         <input type="text" name="Documento[]" class="form-control" placeholder="RG da pessoa autorizada" value="">
      </td>
      <td  style="padding: 5px">
         <input type="text" name="OrgaoEmissor[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Órgão Emissor" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </td>
      <td style="padding: 5px" valign="top"><button type="button" class="removerCampo btn btn-danger" title="Remover linha"><i class="fa fa-minus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> Remover</button></td>
  <tr>
      <td colspan="3"><button type="button" class="adicionarCampo btn btn-primary" title="Adicionar item"><i class="fa fa-plus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> Adicionar mais passageiros</button></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  <div class="text-right">
    <strong>Valor do Pacote:</strong> <span style="font-family: Arial"> R$ 150,00</span><br>
    <strong>Valor Total:</strong> <span style="font-family: Arial"> R$ 0,00</span>
  </div>
```

**JQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {
   function removeCampo() {
         $(".removerCampo").unbind("click");
         $(".removerCampo").bind("click", function () {
            if($("tr.linhas").length > 1){
                 $(this).parent().parent().remove();
            }
         });
   }
   $(".adicionarCampo").click(function () {
      if ($('.linhas').length < 15) {
          var adulto = '<?php echo $visualizar[1]->ValorAdulto; ?>';
          var crianca6Anos = '<?php echo $visualizar[1]->ValorCrianca6Anos; ?>';
          var crianca6a12Anos = '<?php echo $visualizar[1]->ValorCrianca6a12Anos; ?>';
          var adolescentes = '<?php echo $visualizar[1]->ValorAdolescentes; ?>';
          novoCampo = $("tr.linhas:first").clone();
          novoCampo.find('input[type="text"]').val("");
          novoCampo.find('select').val("");
          novoCampo.insertAfter("tr.linhas:last");
          removeCampo();
      }
    });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Onde estão as informações de valores (preços) no código? E esse `.prop('checked',true)` se refere a quê? Olhando o código não visualizei nenhum checkbox ou radiobutton.

Comment: Alterei o código Sam. os valores virão do BD através do PHP.

Comment: Campoa+campob+campoc, porque nao calcular ao aparecer o numero?

Comment: Certo. Traz no formato 140.00.

Comment: Não estou querendo ser cético Sam, mas é possível fazer esse cálculo automático? Pergunto pois, como estou lidando com valores referentes a tipos diferenciados de passageiros, como vou poder fazer para que, depois do quinto campo, ao selecionar Adolescentes, identificar quantos campos selecionados como Adolescentes foram escolhidos anteriormente? Não sei se ficou claro minha dúvida. Até peguei a solução que você passou no post anterior para tentar aqui, mas é exatamente nesse ponto que não consigo avançar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro tem que alterar esses `id`'s para `class`: `id="TipoPassageiro"` e `id="TipoDocumento"`; porque ao clonar você irá duplicar `id`'s, o que é incorreto.

Outro erro é que os dois selects estão com o mesmo name: `name="TipoDocumento[]"`.

Para somar os valores à medida que são alterados os selects, a sugestão é criar um evento `change` que percorrerá os selects fazendo a soma e depois jogar o resultado num `span` que guarda o valor total.

Coloque o valor total (sem o `R$`) dentro de um `span` com um `id`:

```
<strong>Valor Total:</strong>
<span style="font-family: Arial">
   R$ <span id="valortotal">0,00</span>
</span>
```

Outra coisa é criar uma forma de identificar os options do select por códigos. Para isso coloque um `data-tipo` em cada option com um número que será o identificador do preço:

```
<select class="TipoPassageiro" name="TipoDocumento[]" class="form-control">
   <option>Pax</option>
   <option data-tipo="1" value="Adulto">Adulto</option>
   <option data-tipo="2" value="Adolescente entre 12 e 18 anos">Adolescente entre 12 e 18 anos</option>
   <option data-tipo="3" value="Criança entre 6 e 12 anos">Criança entre 6 e 12 anos</option>
   <option data-tipo="4" value="Criança de colo de até 6 anos">Criança de colo de até 6 anos</option>
</select>
```

Então, tipo 1 = adulto, tipo 2 = adolescente etc..

No evento `change` crie um objeto onde cada item se refere a um tipo de valor, e não precisa colocar entre aspas os preços, já que as decimais são separadas por `.` (ponto):

```
$(document).on("change", ".TipoPassageiro", function(){

   // objeto com os preços separados por "tipo"
    var precos = {
       tipo1: 140.50,
       tipo2: 120.00,
       tipo3: 90.00,
       tipo4: 60.10
    }

    // inicia o valor total com 0
    var valor_total = 0;

    // laço que irá percorrer os selects e somar de acordo com o tipo selecionado
    $(".TipoPassageiro").each(function(){

       // pega o valor do tipo (1, 2, 3 ou 4)
       var tipo = $("option:selected", this).data("tipo");

       // só inclui na soma o select que tiver um tipo selecionado
       if(tipo) valor_total += parseFloat(precos['tipo'+tipo]);
    });

    // formata a soma final com duas casas decimais separadas por vírgula
    $("#valortotal").text(valor_total.toFixed(2).replace(".", ","));

 });
```

É só substituir os preços acima pelo código PHP. Ao fazer as somas usei `parseFloat()` caso em algum momento for usar valores com centavos.

**Exemplo:**

```js
$(function () {
   
   function removeCampo() {
         $(".removerCampo").unbind("click");
         $(".removerCampo").bind("click", function () {
            if($("tr.linhas").length > 1){
                 $(this).parent().parent().remove();
            }
         });
   }
   $(".adicionarCampo").click(function () {
      if ($('.linhas').length < 15) {
          novoCampo = $("tr.linhas:first").clone();
          novoCampo.find('input[type="text"]').val("");
          novoCampo.find('select').val("");
          novoCampo.insertAfter("tr.linhas:last");
          removeCampo();
      }
    });
    
   $(document).on("change", ".TipoPassageiro", function(){
   
       var precos = {
          tipo1: 140.50,
          tipo2: 120.00,
          tipo3: 90.00,
          tipo4: 60.10
       }
       
       var valor_total = 0;
   
       $(".TipoPassageiro").each(function(){
          var tipo = $("option:selected", this).data("tipo");
          if(tipo) valor_total += parseFloat(precos['tipo'+tipo]);
       });
      
       $("#valortotal").text(valor_total.toFixed(2).replace(".", ","));
   
    });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="0" width="100%">
  <tr class='linhas'>
    <td>
    <table border="0" width="100%">
      <tr>
        <td  style="padding: 5px">
         <select class="TipoPassageiro" name="TipoDocumento[]" class="form-control">
            <option>Pax</option>
            <option data-tipo="1" value="Adulto">Adulto</option>
            <option data-tipo="2" value="Adolescente entre 12 e 18 anos">Adolescente entre 12 e 18 anos</option>
            <option data-tipo="3" value="Criança entre 6 e 12 anos">Criança entre 6 e 12 anos</option>
            <option data-tipo="4" value="Criança de colo de até 6 anos">Criança de colo de até 6 anos</option>
         </select>
        </td>
      <td  style="padding: 5px"><input type="text" name="NomePAX[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome do pax" value=""></td>
      <td  style="padding: 5px">
        <select class="TipoDocumento" name="TipoDocumento[]" class="form-control">
          <option>Tipo de documento</option>
          <option value="Carteira de Identidade">Carteira de Identidade</option>
          <option value="Carteira Nacional de Habilitação">Carteira Nacional de Habilitação</option>
          <option value="Carteira de Trabalho">Carteira de Trabalho</option>
          <option value="Certidão de Nascimento">Certidão de Nascimento</option>
          <option value="Passaporte">Passaporte</option>
          <option value="Cédula de Identidade Estrangeira">Cédula de Identidade Estrangeira</option>
          <option value="Outros">Outros</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td  style="padding: 5px">
         <input type="text" name="Documento[]" class="form-control" placeholder="RG da pessoa autorizada" value="">
      </td>
      <td  style="padding: 5px">
         <input type="text" name="OrgaoEmissor[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Órgão Emissor" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </td>
      <td style="padding: 5px" valign="top"><button type="button" class="removerCampo btn btn-danger" title="Remover linha"><i class="fa fa-minus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> Remover</button></td>
  <tr>
      <td colspan="3"><button type="button" class="adicionarCampo btn btn-primary" title="Adicionar item"><i class="fa fa-plus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> Adicionar mais passageiros</button></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  <div class="text-right">
    <strong>Valor do Pacote:</strong> <span style="font-family: Arial"> R$ 150,00</span><br>
    <strong>Valor Total:</strong> <span style="font-family: Arial"> R$ <span id="valortotal">0,00</span></span>
  </div>
```

Comment: Excelente Sam. Juro que pensei ser impossível. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Fico contente que tenha dado certo.